# Complete Node Failure in Elasticsearch domain hosted in AWS

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I am having a ES domain hosted in AWS the cluster of 6 nodes with 6 shards 2 primary  and 3 replica shards its very basic setup of ES. The primary shards are on node 1-3 and the replica shards on 4-6  nodes.  But I understand when one of the node holding primary goes down elasticsearch automatically  enables the replica as primary.  But how to recover the data in the node which  went down let say i won't able to restore that  back so how move the data of that  node to new node. Or should just  add a new nodes and it will start the replica of the newly elected primary  shard?  Could anyone please help me understanding this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mostly, the data will be common in primary and replica shards.

If you can't restore the lost machine. (in your case)

You can add a new node, it will automatically create the replica. Once all the replica shards are initialized, it will balance the cluster by spreading primary & replica shards.